# Get 'Application Display Name' in C# / UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

[According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appdisplayinfo.displayname?view=winrt-19041) I can just use this: `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppDisplayInfo.DisplayName`

But I get error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AppDisplayInfo.DisplayName`

I can't add 'AppDiagnostics' capability or use the Package Display name which seems to be the most common solutions for this. Is the documentation wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the `DisplayName` of your current project, you can use the following code without the need to declare the `appDiagnostics` capability:

```
string displayName = Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo.Current.DisplayInfo.DisplayName;
```

If you want the `DisplayName` of all running apps including UWP apps, Win32 apps, system services and so on, you need to add the `appDiagnostics` capability in manifest first.

Check the steps to add the `appDiagnostics` capability:

1. Add `xmlns:rescap` in `Package` and add `rescap` in `IgnorableNamespaces`. Then, add the `appDiagnostics` capability in `Capabilities`.

```
    <Package   xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" 
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
      <Capabilities>
        <rescap:Capability Name="appDiagnostics" />
      </Capabilities>
    </Package>
```

2. The `appDiagnostics` capability is a restricted capability, you need to get the permission from users. A user-consent prompt will be triggered at the first time calling the diagnostic APIs such as `AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoAsync()`. Or users can open **Settings** panel, find the **Privacy** option and set the **App Diagnostics**.

[image]

Note that if permission is denied by users, then the APIs will only return information about the current app.

3. Add the following code to view the `DisplayName` of all running apps.

```
var list = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoAsync();
foreach (var info in list)
{
    string name = info.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName;
}
```

Comment: `AppInfo.Current` was added in Windows 10 SDK version 2004, so check your SDK version if you (like me) were wondering why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

If someone needs it for the WinUI 3

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.DisplayName
```

Comment: if I'm remembering correctly - I couldn't use the "Package" display name because it was different than the "Application" display name (what shows in the app title bar). I don't remember exactly